# How to retain the preceding updated row values in PySpark and use it in the next row calculation?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

The below condition needs to be applied on RANK and RANKA columns

Input table:

[image: input]

**Condition for RANK column:**

- IF RANK == 0 : then RANK= previous RANK value + 1 ;
- else :            RANK=RANK

**Condition for RANKA column:**

- IF RANKA == 0 : then RANKA= previous RANKA value + current row Salary
  value;
- else :         RANKA=RANKA

**Below is a piece of code that I tried.**

I have created dummy columns named ***RANK_new*** and ***RANKA_new*** for storing the desired outputs of RANK and RANKA columns after applying conditions.
And then once I get the correct values I can replace the RANK and RANKA column with those dummy columns.

```py
# importing necessary libraries
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col
# function to create new SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag,lead
def create_session():
    spk = SparkSession.builder \
        .master("local") \
        .appName("employee_profile.com") \
        .getOrCreate()
    return spk
 
 
def create_df(spark, data, schema):
    df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
    return df1
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    # calling function to create SparkSession
    spark = create_session()
 
    input_data = [(1, "Shivansh", "Data Scientist", 2,1,1,2),
                  (0, "Rishabh", "Software Developer", 5,2,0,3),
                  (0, "Swati", "Data Analyst", 10,3,10,4),
                  (1, "Amar", "Data Analyst", 2,4,9,0),
                  (0, "Arpit", "Android Developer", 3,5,0,0),
                  (0, "Ranjeet", "Python Developer", 4,6,0,0),
                  (0, "Priyanka", "Full Stack Developer",5,7,0,0)]
 
    schema = ["Id", "Name", "Job Profile", "Salary",'hi','RANK','RANKA'] 
    # calling function to create dataframe
    dff = create_df(spark, input_data, schema) 
    
    # Below 3 lines for RANK
    df1=dff.repartition(1)  
    df2 = df1.withColumn('RANK_new', when(col('RANK') == 0,lag(col('RANK')+lit(1)).over(Window.orderBy(col('hi')))).otherwise(col('RANK')))
    df2 = df2.withColumn('RANK_new', when((col('RANK') == 0) & (lag(col('RANK')).over(Window.orderBy(col('hi'))) == 0) ,lag(col('RANK_new')+lit(1)).over(Window.orderBy(col('hi')))).otherwise(col('RANK_new')))
    
    #Below line for RANKA
    df2=df2.withColumn('RANKA_new', when(col('RANKA') == 0, lag(col("RANKA")).over(Window.orderBy("hi"))+col("Salary")).otherwise(col('RANKA')))
    df2.show()
```

The issue with this code is that **the lag function is not taking the updated values of the previous rows.**
**This can be done with a for loop but since my data is so huge, I need a solution without for loop.**

Below is the desired output:

[image: Desired output]

Below is a summarized picture to show the Output I got and the desired output.

**RANK_new, RANKA_new** --> These are the output I got for RANK and RANKA columns after I applied the above code

**RANK_desired, RANKA-desired** ---> **This is what is expected to be produced**.

[image: summarized]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create groups for partitioning for both, RANK and RANKA. Then using `sum` inside partitions should work.

Input

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
input_data = [(1, "Shivansh", "Data Scientist", 2,1,1,2),
              (0, "Rishabh", "Software Developer", 5,2,0,3),
              (0, "Swati", "Data Analyst", 10,3,10,4),
              (1, "Amar", "Data Analyst", 2,4,9,0),
              (0, "Arpit", "Android Developer", 3,5,0,0),
              (0, "Ranjeet", "Python Developer", 4,6,0,0),
              (0, "Priyanka", "Full Stack Developer",5,7,0,0)]
schema = ["Id", "Name", "Job Profile", "Salary",'hi','RANK','RANKA'] 
dff = spark.createDataFrame(input_data, schema)
```

Script:

```py
w0 = W.orderBy('hi')

rank_grp = F.when(F.col('RANK') != 0, 1).otherwise(0)
dff = dff.withColumn('RANK_grp', F.sum(rank_grp).over(w0))
w1 = W.partitionBy('RANK_grp').orderBy('hi')

ranka_grp = F.when(F.col('RANKA') != 0, 1).otherwise(0)
dff = dff.withColumn('RANKA_grp', F.sum(ranka_grp).over(w0))
w2 = W.partitionBy('RANKA_grp').orderBy('hi')

dff = (dff
    .withColumn('RANK_new', F.sum(F.when(F.col('RANK') == 0, 1).otherwise(F.col('RANK'))).over(w1))
    .withColumn('RANKA_new', F.sum(F.when(F.col('RANKA') == 0, F.col('Salary')).otherwise(F.col('RANKA'))).over(w2))
    .drop('RANK_grp', 'RANKA_grp')
)

dff.show()
# +---+--------+--------------------+------+---+----+-----+--------+---------+
# | Id|    Name|         Job Profile|Salary| hi|RANK|RANKA|RANK_new|RANKA_new|
# +---+--------+--------------------+------+---+----+-----+--------+---------+
# |  1|Shivansh|      Data Scientist|     2|  1|   1|    2|       1|        2|
# |  0| Rishabh|  Software Developer|     5|  2|   0|    3|       2|        3|
# |  0|   Swati|        Data Analyst|    10|  3|  10|    4|      10|        4|
# |  1|    Amar|        Data Analyst|     2|  4|   9|    0|       9|        6|
# |  0|   Arpit|   Android Developer|     3|  5|   0|    0|      10|        9|
# |  0| Ranjeet|    Python Developer|     4|  6|   0|    0|      11|       13|
# |  0|Priyanka|Full Stack Developer|     5|  7|   0|    0|      12|       18|
# +---+--------+--------------------+------+---+----+-----+--------+---------+
```